# Please help me with my PC build

Tags: computer-building

This is my current build:

[image: build sheet]

([Larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X1sk.png))

Could you please review it?
I have also been told that the socket on the motherboard I've chosen is not adequate for the CPU I've selected, and also that I should consider investing my money into an AMD Phenom II X6 1090T Black core instead of an Intel i7 2600k. What do you think about this? And the build in general?

I will be using my PC mostly for Video Games, Photoshop, 3D Graphics, Mapping, Programming and Video Editing. My budget is flexible and around 1200€. (Roughly 1635$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a shopping recommendation. I recommend you find a trusted computer hardware review site for information like this. MaximumPC is my favorite site for such lists of great hardware.

Regarding the one specific question in your post, here's an answer:

From what I can tell (the image is pretty small), you've got an 1155 socket MB for yout 2600k CPU. This is the correct socket for that CPU, you should not have socket issues.

**(Opinion Alert!)** Regarding recommendations to go with an AMD proc vs the Intel, that is entirely opinion. The 2600k CPUs have been getting very good reviews for a while, and it has been even longer since I have seen an AMD proc really truly beat out an Intel CPU at the same price point. Others may have different experiences, but from what I can tell now, just about every review mag has noted the 2600k is a very good processor at a pretty good price.

Comment: You can right click on the image to open it in a new tab :) Sorry if it's small.
By the way, I've also been told that the 1155 socket is the wrong one for my CPU and Intel uses another one which gives it more performance. Is that true?

Comment: Socket has very little to do with performance, and has very much to do with limiting whichi chips can run with which mainboards and chipsets. The socket 1156 supports older i-series CPUs, but the newer "2000" sub-series of the i-series CPUs require the newer 1155. Yes, it has one less pin. That's all it needs to keep you from running an 1156 CPU in an 1155 board and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

First off I think preference between AMD and Intel is a decision only you can make. So I won't voice my opinions about that.

The specs of the MB match the CPU type so they would be compatible. Newegg even had this review as the first one on the list regarding that MB.

From [Newegg.com - Asus MB](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131730)

"Pros: Excellent board for OC and daily use. Provides consistant (and reliable) performance of 5.0 Ghz with Intel's 2600K. Auto OC's at 4.5 Ghz."

The build in general looks pretty high tech and I would imagine you can throw tons of stuff at it, and if a near top of the line build is what you are after I think you have it. Just make sure it stays cool.

Comment: Does you saying that the thing between AMD and Intel is completely personal also imply that I cannot get better/different performance for higher/lower prices?

Comment: My opinion is I would go amd anyday. But thats just what I used in my build. its kinda like comparing coke and pepsi. Ya just gotta read some reviews and feedback that resembles you build and see if its what you want in the end

Comment: Also if you went amd youd have to change boards. Visit newegg.com and read some user reviews some people may have built the same combo.